# Running a bootstrapper on Windows 2000

Tags: .net, bootstrapper

Is there any way how to run the setup.exe bootstrapper generated by VS2008 with .NET 2.0 WinForms application on Windows 2000 SP4? If I try to run it, it gives me an error message about missing HeapSetInformation in Kernel32.dll and it doesn't run.

I tried to install manually Windows Installer 3.1 and also .NET 2.0 Framework, but the setup.exe still shows the same error message. I have to use Setup.msi directly to install my app on Windows 2000. Is the bootstrapper limited to be used only on XP and higher?

It runs OK on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrapper typically will create a log file in a sub folder of your %TMP% folder. Are there any information in the log?

Users in other forums suggest installing [Update Rollup 1 for Windows 2000 SP4 (KB891861)](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=B54730CF-8850-4531-B52B-BF28B324C662&displaylang=en) to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no log file in `profile/Temp` or `C:\windows\Temp`

The Update Rollup really works, thanks!